# Swiftlint Autocorrect Does Not Modify File

Tags: swift, macos, swiftlint

In running `swiftlint` version 0.24.0, errors are reported. Running `autocorrect` states that the files have been corrected. Yet no modifications are made as a subsequent run of `swiftlint` proves.

See the attempt to lint and correct two files `Player.swift` and `Prize.swift`.

```
MacBook-Pro-5: Developer$ swiftlint 
Loading configuration from '.swiftlint.yml'
Linting Swift files in current working directory
Linting 'Prize.swift' (1/2)
Linting 'Player.swift' (2/2)
Player.swift:26:19: warning: Operator Function Whitespace Violation: Operators should be surrounded by a single whitespace when defining them. (operator_whitespace)
Player.swift:27: warning: Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 131 characters (line_length)
Player.swift:39: warning: Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 147 characters (line_length)
Prize.swift:44:34: warning: Colon Violation: Colons should be next to the identifier when specifying a type and next to the key in dictionary literals. (colon)
Prize.swift:44: error: Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 210 characters (line_length)
Done linting! Found 5 violations, 1 serious in 2 files.
MacBook-Pro-5: Developer$ swiftlint autocorrect
Loading configuration from '.swiftlint.yml'
Correcting Swift files in current working directory
Correcting 'Prize.swift' (1/2)
Correcting 'Player.swift' (2/2)
Done correcting 2 files!
MacBook-Pro-5: Developer$ swiftlint 
Loading configuration from '.swiftlint.yml'
Linting Swift files in current working directory
Linting 'Prize.swift' (1/2)
Linting 'Player.swift' (2/2)
Prize.swift:44:34: warning: Colon Violation: Colons should be next to the identifier when specifying a type and next to the key in dictionary literals. (colon)
Prize.swift:44: error: Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 210 characters (line_length)
Player.swift:26:19: warning: Operator Function Whitespace Violation: Operators should be surrounded by a single whitespace when defining them. (operator_whitespace)
Player.swift:27: warning: Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 131 characters (line_length)
Player.swift:39: warning: Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 147 characters (line_length)
Done linting! Found 5 violations, 1 serious in 2 files.
MacBook-Pro-5: Developer$
```

Here's another run but this time with one file `Prize.swift` containing only one correctable violation. Again, `autocorrect` does not modify:

```
MacBook-Pro-5:P Developer$ swiftlint 
Linting Swift files in current working directory
Linting 'Prize.swift' (1/2)
Linting 'Player.swift' (2/2)
PPrize.swift:44:34: warning: Colon Violation: Colons should be next to the identifier when specifying a type and next to the key in dictionary literals. (colon)
Done linting! Found 1 violation, 0 serious in 2 files.
MacBook-Pro-5:P Developer$ swiftlint autocorrect
Correcting Swift files in current working directory
Correcting 'Prize.swift' (1/2)
Correcting 'Player.swift' (2/2)
Done correcting 2 files!
MacBook-Pro-5:P Developer$ swiftlint 
Linting Swift files in current working directory
Linting 'Prize.swift' (1/2)
Linting 'Player.swift' (2/2)
PPrize.swift:44:34: warning: Colon Violation: Colons should be next to the identifier when specifying a type and next to the key in dictionary literals. (colon)
Done linting! Found 1 violation, 0 serious in 2 files.
MacBook-Pro-5:P Developer$
```

Note that the presence or not of a `.swiftlint.yml` file had zero bearing on this.

Abbreviated - that is, only showing relevant rules - output from `swiftlint rules` is shown below. Note that of the three violations, `colon` is definitely correctable.

```
MacBook-Pro-5: Developer$ swiftlint rules
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| identifier                               | opt-in | correctable | enabled in your config | kind        | configuration                                                                                                             |
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| colon                                    | no     | yes         | yes                    | style       | warning, flexible_right_spacing: false, apply_to_dictionaries: true                                                       |
| line_length                              | no     | no          | yes                    | metrics     | warning: 120, error: 200, ignores urls: false, ignores function declarations: false, ignores comments: false              |
| operator_whitespace                      | no     | no          | yes                    | style       | warning                                                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any thoughts on how `swiftlint autocorrect` can run successfully? Might there be some obvious configuration or parameter I am missing? I have consulted https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

**updated** 
`swiftlint autocorrect --format` 
`swiftlint --fix --format` 
`swiftlint lint --fix --format`

will work for all. source: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/3571

**old** 
if `swiftlint` version below 0.42.0
then you can auto correct it using `swiftlint autocorrect --format`

but if its 0.43.0 or higher then you need to use `swiftlint --fix`

it will auto correct the white space, trailing space, initial formating, bracket in if else. etc. which will not affect on your logics or codes.

`swiftlint autocorrect --format` //for version < 0.42.0 
`swiftlint --fix` //for latest version >= 0.43.0

Answer (score 3):

Not all SwiftLint rules are correctable, which mean that they will remain after you run `swiftlint autocorrect`. If you run `swiftlint rules` you can see a table that – among other things – show which rules are correctable.

I'm not sure what version of SwiftLint you are using, but I don't think `line_length` or `operator_whitespace` are correctable. You will have to deal with those yourself.

Comment: Added detail to the question. I'm wondering if - for example - a file has three violations of which just one is correctable - autocorrect simply ignores the file.

Sometimes autocorrect does appear to work.

Note that the question is an abbreviated example. I've been running autocorrect against a workspace with hundreds of files and correctable violations. Of say 620 files, autocorrect will fix perhaps 4. I don't know why and I don't know why those specific files are corrected. Feels like something obvious is missing. Just don't know what.

Comment: this could be a bug in the latest version. I am currently using 0.23 and it works fine. sometimes it cant fix particular cases, but fixes everything else